# Difficult diminutives

Tags: gramática, diminutivos

Diminutives are easy to get a hang of for relatively simple nouns: add *-inho* / *-inha* if ending in *-o* / *-a* or *-s* or *-z* (*carr|inho*, *Japones|inho*) or *-zinho* / *-zinha* otherwise (*cafe|zinho*)

But I'm not sure how form diminutives for words, which are somehow "irregular", e.g.

- masculine nouns ending in *-a*
- feminine nouns which irregular stress, or
- words, which end in something already containing *-nh-*.

Which of the following would be correct (or most common)?

- **idioma** (or *poeta* or *problema*)
  o idiominha¹, a idiominha², o idiominho³, o idiomazinho⁴
  <sub>¹ because *idioma* is masculine, but ends in *-a*</sub>
  <sub>² because the word ends in *-a* and the ending *-inha* is feminine</sub>
  <sub>³ because *idioma* is masculine, and the ending *-inho/a* has to match gender</sub>
  <sub>⁴ because idioma is too irregular to use *-inho/a*</sub>
- **língua**
  a linguinha, a linguazinha
- **lenha**
  a lenhinha, a lenhazinha
- **mandioquinha** (not a small *mandioca*, but rather [this](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandioquinha))
  a mandioquinhinha, a mandioquinhazinha

Comment: "mandioquinha" is already a diminutive of "mandioca". Further for "língua", the diminutive is "linguinha". About "idioma" and "lenha", I never saw or read those in diminutive, so I suspect that there are no diminutives for those.

Comment: Well, [mandioquinha](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandioquinha) is not a "small mandioca" but a different tuber, more like a potato. Instead of _idioma_ I could ask about _problema_ or _poeta_.

Comment: Yes, it is a different tuber, but it was (mis)named as a diminutive of "mandioca". The same way as that "camisinha" should be the diminutive of "camisa", but it really got a very different meaning because the diminutive form was later attributed to something completely different.

Comment: Does that mean it doesn't have a diminutive? (small little cute mandioquinha)

Comment: I am unsure about this, but I think that yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't find the rules in the literature, so this is my answer as a native speaker from Portugal. A few things below might not apply in Brasil.

All the cases you referred use the diminutive version -zinho/a.
In these cases the root word is unchanged, that is, no ending letters are dropped, as is the case with the suffix -inho/a.

- Masculine nouns ending in *-a* : use the suffix -zinho (but see below)

> problema - problemazinho
>   poeta - poetazinho
>   um jornalista - jornalistazinho
>   uma jornalista - jornalistazinha

However, in Brasil, you can hear the version *probleminha*, which is not heard in Portugal.

- Following diphthongs : use the suffix -zinho or -zinha

> língua - línguazinha
>   coração - coraçãozinho
>   rádio - radiozinho
>
> **Note:** comboio - comboinho
>   (perhaps because the last *o* is outside the diphthong)

- Nouns ending in -nh- : use the suffix -zinho/a

> moinho - moinhozinho
>   caminho - caminhozinho
>   façanha - façanhazinha
>
> **Note:**
>   castanho (adj) - castanhinho
>   castanha (noun) - castanhinha or castanhazinha

Note that some nouns and adjectives can accept both forms of diminutive, most commonly in words related to food:

> fruta - frutinha or frutazinha
>   carne - carninha or carnezinha

Be also aware of the uses of diminutive forms. At least in Portugal, they are preferred when:

- speaking to children
- talking about food or shopping food
- in situations where we mean to be ironic.

Of course, they are used to refer to things that are small, but there are many words of which I have never heard the diminutive form, and couldn't tell how they would sound like.