# Diminutives with -ola

Tags: diminutivos, sufixos

As a follow-up to [Difficult diminutives](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/368/64), my daughter just brought home a homework, where she is supposed to find diminutives with *-inho* and *-ola*. I've never seen or heard diminutives with *-ola*, and the formation isn't listed in my [Modern Brazilian Portuguese Grammar](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0415566444).

The suffix *-ola* is listed in Aurélio

> #### -ola¹
>
> [Poss. do it. *-ola* ou do fr. *-ole*, ambos do lat. *-ola*.]
>   Sufixo nominal.
>
> 1. = 'diminuição': *bandeirola, portinhola, rapazola*. [Em palavras como *patetola* e *beiçola*, significa, ironicamente, o oposto.]

The homework was set with

```
          |  -inho   |   -ola
==========|==========|==========
bandeira  |          |
porta     |          |
rapaz     |          |
```

exactly the three words which appear in the Aurélio entry. Is the suffix *-ola* still productive, that is, can I form the diminutive of any word with it?

In the case of *bandeirinha ↔ bandeirola*, the former appears to be football/soccer slang for assistant referees (those with the little flags), so I see why one would want two diminutives.

In the case of *portinhola ↔ portinha*, I'm not so sure of the difference (plus, the formation seems to be irregular: is there a word *portola*, too?).

> **portinhola**
>   1. Pequena porta
>   2. [...]
>
> **<s>portinha</s>**
>   [no entry, presumably meaning "pequena porta"?]

Can anyone explain more about the differences between these diminutives?

Comment: It's a very difficult question. In my opinion the suffix *-ola* is smaller than *-inho* in this cases but it's only an "achismo".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add the suffix *(z)inho* to pretty much any noun to form a diminutive usually expressing the idea that the thing is little or likeable. You can even add *(z)inho* to adjectives.

It is a different case with the suffix *ola*. People don’t usually make up new words with it as they do with *(z)inho*, and that is why it is new to you.
And most of the words that exist with *ola* aren’t simply smaller or likeable versions of their root word; often they’re not small at all, or particularly likeable. They typically have a meaning of their own, deserving their own entry in the dictionaries when their *(z)inho* siblings do not. Here are a few examples:

> [**Rapazola**](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/rapazola) is an older teenager.
>   [**Criançola**](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/crian%C3%A7ola) is someone who's no longer a child but is more childish than we would like.
>   [**Bandeirola**](http://www.aulete.com.br/bandeirola) is a small flag used for signalling or showing boundaries of fields.
>   [**Galinhola**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galinhola) is the name of several wild birds not related to the chicken.
>   [**Camisola**](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/camisola) is a nightdress in Brazil and a jersey, sweater in Portugal.
>   [**Portinhola**](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/portinhola) (*portinh(a) + ola*) is indeed a small door, especially in a coach or a hatch in a ship.
>   [**Aldeola**](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/aldeola) is indeed a small village.
>   [**Quintarola**](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/quintarola) (*quinta*, farm, + *ola*) is a small farm.

I would say words with *-ola* will typically mean one or both of two things. One is that the thing is in some sense not the very best of its kind. For instance, an *aldeola* is a small *aldeia*; *quintarola* a small *quinta*; a *criançola* is the wrong type of ‘criança’; a *graçola* is not that funny.

Another possibility is that the thing is not bad or small at all, and the speaker, perhaps co-opting the previous notion, is simply trying to convey a light-hearted, somewhat playful attitude towards the thing. So it expresses some familiarity but not the sentimentality and ‘lamechice’ of the *-inho* word. This is the case of words such as *cervejola* and *dentola*, and that’s what I would infer if I heard made-up words such as in:

> “Não queres comer esta *bananola*?” "Não, quero antes aquela *maçãzola*.”
>   “Vá, salta para a banheira: vamos lá lavar essa *cabeçola*!”

The two features may be combined in words such as *festarola*, *jantarola*; maybe not the best of their kinds, but we still like them.

Some derogatory epithets can take the suffix -*olas* too:

> Sempre me saíste um **doidolas!**
>   És um [**bebedolas!**](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/bebedolas)

And the only example I can think of that derives from a verb (I can’t believe I had forgotten this crucial specimen):

> Não passas dum [**cagarolas!**](http://www.aulete.com.br/cagarolas)

Some *-ola* words have meanings only tenuously related to the root word, and defy classification. For instance, [*castanhola*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castanhola) is a musical instrument that looks vaguely like a *castanha* or chestnut. *Camisola* is not an inferior type of *camisa*, it is just a jersey whereas a camisa is a shirt. So when you come across a new *-ola* word it may be best to look it up in a dictionary: its meaning might not be guessable from the root word in a predictable way.

Comment: Qual é que te parece que é o significado de "-ola"? O sufixo não me parece muito produtivo, mas se visses uma palavra nova com "-ola", imaginemos uma "tigelola" (de "tigela"), o que é que dirias que era?

Comment: Isto para ser um bom teste, não devias dizer donde é que vinha. Diria que era um tigela, talvez um bocado mal-feitona. Mais provavelmente seria o falante a brincar. Não a imaginaria pequena. Acho duvidoso chamar-se diminutivo às palavras formadas com o sufixo "-ola".

Comment: Talvez o falante se referisse à tigela por "tigelola" em vez de "tigelinha" pela mesma razão que um pai em Portugal se refere ao filho por "meu puto" em vez de "meu filhinho". Para não ser tão piegolas.

Comment: Sim, também me parece ser essa mais ou menos a ideia, de tirar seriedade à coisa, como em "cervejola", "festarola" e, como dizes, até ter uma carga ligeiramente negativa como em "graçola" (mas não tanto um diminutivo mais depreciativo como "-eco"). Mas também acho que a ideia de "diminutivo" não é completamente descabida.

Comment: Once I heard someone say "tiazola", meaning someone old, conservative and not very active. Although it's rare to use this suffix to create new words, it happens. And it feels it carries something pejorative.

Comment: Not always. There's nothing pejorative about cervejola.

Comment: "You can also form words with adjective + -ola or + -olas." Mas depois os exemplos que dás são usos como nome: "um doidolas", "um bebedolas", onde seria mais razoável dizer que vêm de "doido (como nome) + olas" e "bêbedo (como nome) + olas".

Comment: O artigo da Sílvia Skorge [aqui](http://cvc.instituto-camoes.pt/conhecer/biblioteca-digital-camoes/lingua-1/244-244/file.html) também tem material sobre _-ola_.

Answer (score 4):

When I posted the question, I thought that maybe there were only maybe three words with diminutives *-ola*, but [@Jacinto's answer](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/1376/64) already lists 8 such words.

In fact, looking through all the words in Aurélio ending in *-ola*, I found a more extensive list of 60+ such words (see below). (Since Aurélio is for Brazilian Portuguese, such a list would probably look different for European Portuguese.)

My impression is that the suffix ***-ola*** was (and maybe still is) [productive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Productivity_%28linguistics%29), but **not to form usual diminutives**.

- *[X]inho* appears to be (literally) a "small cute" X, but
- *[X]ola* might be something that

  - *shares some (but not all) characteristics with* small X
  - *looks like* or *acts like* a small X, or
  - maybe is a *special type* of small X.

Moreover, most if not all have a special meaning, as implied by the fact that they are all listed separately in the dictionary.

---

- absidíola
- aldeola
- arteríola
- asneirola
- bana(n)zola?
- bandeirola
- bandola
- barbeirola
- beiçola
- bractéola
- cachola
- caixola
- camisola
- cantarola
- caranguejola
- carriola
- casinhola
- castanhola
- chacarola
- corriola
- criançola
- dançarola
- dentola
- drupéola
- eletrola
- esquírola
- estanciola
- farsola
- fazendola
- festarola
- fovéola
- gabarola
- galéola
- galinhola
- graçola
- grafonola
- granjola
- herdadola
- historíola
- igrejola
- jantarola
- lauréola
- marola
- mentirola
- passarola
- patetola
- patola
- picola
- portinhola
- quartola
- quintarola
- rabichola
- rabiola
- rapazola
- rubéola
- sachola
- sacola
- tendola
- terriola
- varola
- vendola

Comment: Of those words I knew 23; 14 others I hadn't heard before but I can guess what they mean; 16 I don't know what they mean; and 7 are not proper X-ola words - they are X-éola or X-íola, and I think they are all fairly technical terms, whereas X-ola are popular words. Are you sure it is *varola* , not *varíola*?

Comment: Correction: there are 10 X-íola/éola words. That makes only 13 X-ola words I can't make out.

Comment: @Jacinto "varola [vara + -ola]. (1) vareta." About the "proper" X-ola words: Some of these are derived from Latin or French words with -ola suffix (with the same meaning), so they are still X-ola words, but in an extended sense. Others have an inserted interfix -i-, but they are still listed as using the suffix -ola.

Comment: I put this list together fairly quickly, but I'm happy to look again at the details for individual items in this list if anyone finds an entry odd or out-of-place.

Comment: If you're aming at a complete list, here's *cervejola* and *bebedolas*. There's also *estarola*, but it is dubious because we're not sure what the root word is. I would place the *-íola, -éola* in a separate category. They are related to the others only in a very formal way. I doubt any native speaker would see them as belonging to the same category. They take masculine forms too: *alvéolo*.

Comment: It's normal for a dictionary to only list derived words whose meaning isn't entirely transparent from the combination of base word and suffix/prefix. So it's a bit of a tautology to say that most of the words with -ola have special meanings based on a dictionary search — you're limiting yourself to lexicalized combinations.

Comment: @guifa OK, but are you saying that the suffix is productive?

Comment: It's probably still at least semi productive since suffix itself is still listed separately. Most dictionaries (especially normative ones) tend to drop entries pre- and suffix entries once they are fully unproductive. Not being a native speaker and coming from ES/AST which have a more productive set of augmentatives/diminutives I'm not the one to ask.

Comment: @Earthliŋ from use, I say that it seems to be productive... if I understood its meaning. You can form new words, such as cervejola, "quimzola", [marmanj](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/marmanjo)ola, etc.